# syndaemon deactivates two finger scrolling and tapping

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with an Elantech touchpad and have multiple issues.

The worst of all is that the standard "deactivate while typing option" is not working and if I activate syndaemon (syndaemon -i 1 -K -d) as soon as I type and syndaemon deactivates the touchpad,  two finger scrolling and touchpad tapping does not work anymore... sometimes the mouse even completely freezes.

Is there anything i can do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this today, with help of very useful [information in the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics).

Basically, in Ubuntu 14.04 you need to create a copy of an X11 config file and add your scrolling and clicking-by-tapping options.

You can find full instructions in [a GitHub repo of mine](https://github.com/invernizzie/sysadmin-bookmarks/blob/master/ubuntu-disable-touchpad-typing.md) that I keep for future reference.

The options you're probably interested in are `VertTwoFingerScroll`, `HorizTwoFingerScroll` and `TapButtonN`.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I've had that issue today, and your approach solved the problem for me :  )

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, @OlivierBégassat ! Unfortunately, OP hasn't accepted the answer.